# What does “temporary faculty pool” mean?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application, terminology

I have seen university career postings for a “temporary faculty pool”. What does this term mean?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the posting in question at least?

Answer (score 3):

Looking up a few such postings, it appears to be another name for ["adjunct faculty"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professors_in_the_United_States#Adjunct_professor).  In other words, [temp work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_work) for academia.